# Adding <th> to the table in js

Tags: javascript, json, html-table

I'm trying to add `<th>` tag to the table, but I am not able to add. I want to add `Id`, `Name` and `Prof` as a table header.

```
var obj=[{id:"01",name:"Bob",prof:"Soft Engg"},{id:"02",name:"George",prof:"Admin"},{id:"03",name:"Paul",prof:"Front End"}];
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.setAttribute("id","myTable");
document.body.appendChild(table);

for(i=0;i<obj.length;i++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr")
  table.appendChild(row);
  var head = document.createElement("th");
  row.appendChild(head);
  for (key in obj[i]) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    row.appendChild(cell);
    cell.innerHTML = obj[i][key];
  }
}
```

Comment: Then on the first iteration, you need to get the keys of the first object and use them as the content of TH cells. Note that the order in which they are returned is not necessarily stable, so your headings may not be consistent with the data. A better idea is to include a header record in *obj* that has them in the right order and that also specifies the related property name so you put the right data in the right column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do  something like this

```js
var obj = [{
  id: "01",
  name: "Bob",
  prof: "Soft Engg"
}, {
  id: "02",
  name: "George",
  prof: "Admin"
}, {
  id: "03",
  name: "Paul",
  prof: "Front End"
}];
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
document.body.appendChild(table);

// check array length
if (obj.length) {
  // create row for table head
  var row = document.createElement("tr")
  // append it to table
  table.appendChild(row);
  // get kesys from first object and iterate
  Object.keys(obj[0]).forEach(function(v) {
    // create th
    var cell = document.createElement("th");
    // append to tr
    row.appendChild(cell);
    // update th content as key value
    cell.innerHTML = v;
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr")
  table.appendChild(row);
  for (key in obj[i]) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    row.appendChild(cell);
    cell.innerHTML = obj[i][key];
  }
}
```

Comment: Working Fine Thanks Bro :)

Comment: @Raja : glad to help

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't stop thinking about this post and use it as JS practice, here I go:

```
var obj=[
{id:"01",name:"Bob",prof:"Soft Engg"},
{id:"02",name:"George",prof:"Admin"},
{id:"03",name:"Paul",prof:"Front End"}
];

var headers=['id','name','prof'];

var table = document.createElement("table");
table.setAttribute("id","myTable");
document.body.appendChild(table);

var tableHeader = document.createElement("thead");
table.appendChild(tableHeader);
tableHeaderRow = document.createElement("tr");
table.appendChild(tableHeaderRow);
for(i=0;i<headers.length;i++){
        var tableHeader = document.createElement("th");
        tableHeaderRow.appendChild(tableHeader);
        tableHeader.innerHTML = headers[i]
}

var tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");
  table.appendChild(tableBody);
 for(i=0;i<headers.length;i++){
    var tbodyrows=document.createElement("tr");
 for (key in obj[i]) {
    tableBody.appendChild(tbodyrows);
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    tbodyrows.appendChild(cell);
    cell.innerHTML = obj[i][key];
  }
}
```